# Is there an Android setting which might be causing the Auth0 universal login to open in-app instead of in the browser?

Tags: java, android, react-native, auth0

I can't get the Auth0 to work on React Native Android, even though it's working just fine on iOS. When I call `authorize()` the first time, the universal login starts inside a browser. Once I input my credentials and click "Login", nothing happens. At that point I'd expect to be redirected back inside my Android app.

Then if I call `authorize()` again, it looks like the Auth0 login URL is being opened in-app instead of in a browser. I confirmed it by checking the currently active applications and not seeing my Chrome active.

Is there an Android setting that might be messing with Auth0 somehow?

Comment: How about on native android ui? I believe it's not related to react. Can you explain your question